# Encode file contents in JSON object

Tags: json, base64, gzip

I need to send a file via JSON.. But is there a more effective way to encode the file than base64?

Base64 increases the file with about 30% and on top of that the compression ratio when gzipping the post (the base64 string) is very poor..

Comment: Base64 is for making binary and non binary data pass equally as text. Gzip is best suited to text. I suggest you reverse the order of operations

Comment: have just tested it and it is ALWAYS better to do base64 encoding first and then gzip

Comment: but its still not very effecient

Comment: Gzip isn't efficient for small data, nor is JSON. What do you mean you "need to send a file via JSON"? JSON has limited data types, binary and file not being among them.

Comment: who cares? space is cheap

Comment: @clarkk did you find a solution? I have the same issue.